# How to update values in hashmap

Tags: java

Can any one tell me how to update values in a hash map

Comment: Too localized? How? This is a valid programming question IMHO. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`put`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29):

> "If the map previously contained a
>   mapping for the key, the old value is
>   replaced."